# Magento 2 home page issue - 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

Tags: magento2.3.4, home-page

How to solve the home page issue,

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

#1 Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Theme->getPatternDirs(array('area' => 'frontend', 'locale' => 'en_US', 'file' => 'i18n/en_US.csv', 'theme_dir' => NULL)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Design\FileResolution\Fallback\Resolver\Simple.php:125]

Answer (score 0):

please check the theme dir path

> app/design/frontend/Vander/theme_dir

and open the Database finds the **theme** table and check your theme parent id.

Comment: d mismatch, now things okay, but css not applied all my pages.

Comment: follow command.
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
PHP bin/magento c:f